# WEBDRIVERIO | Dropdown option bounces back to default value

Tags: webdriver-io

Dropdown values are bouncing back to default as soon as the framework tries to interact with other elements?

```
super.stateDropdown().click(); //opens the dropdown menu
super.stateOption(address.state).click(); //selects the state
super.continueButton().click(); // tries to submit the form, but the state value bounces back to default
```

**What I tried**

- selectByValue()

  selectByAttribute()

  click() the drop down and click() the value while the options are
  displayed

  javascript click ( Helpers.jsClick() )

  wait 10 secs before clicking next element

  $(element).moveTo() + browser.preformActions()

Any other ways to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

Is `continueButton()` a function? If it is a function then the `click` command should return an error. If you are using page objects and it refers to the selector which you named `continueButton` then you should use it without `()`.

Did you also check on your page how many elements use the same selector as `continueButton`?

Maybe you can share the logging you get when running the tests. There is probably some more information there.

Comment: Correct.  continiueButtion() returns the element and it correctly click on it with no issues or error.

The issue is the state value returns back to default when I click.

Eg,
super.stateOption('CA').click(); - sets the state to CA 
super.continueButton().click(); - the state switches  back to AK